# Is it possible to set UIView's top relative to other UIView's height using AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

Is it possible to set `UIView`'s `top` relative to other `UIView`'s `height` using AutoLayout? In other words, I want to give a view different top values depending on height of screen size.

For example, I want a result of third one not second on the following image.
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the result you are aiming, you can use a little "hack", adding three accessory UIView (with clear background):

- **View #1** above the blue UIView, with a constraint = 0 to `Top Layout Guide`
- **View #2** between the blue and purple views
- **View #3** below the purple UIView, with a constraint = 0 to `Bottom Layout Guide`

Next, you need to add two other constraints, `Equal Widths` between Views **#1 and #2**, and between Views **#2 and #3**

Finally, you need to add `Vertical Spacing` constraints (= 0) between all the views, linking each view with the one below (or over). The key here is to lock those views between them, so that the vertical layout is not ambigous.

Now you can just add a specific height constraint to blue & purple view and they will stay in place, floating if screen size changes.

> Note #1: Be sure to constraint these accessory views to the Main ViewController view, in order to center them & fit them to parent width
>
> Note #2: If you don't know their height before, this solution will *not* work. You could try with some constraint set to `Greater Than` while playing with priorities but I didn't test it.

### Interface Builder screenshot

[image: Interface Builder to achieve equally distributed views]